# É possível ter um split() com duas ou mais condições no Python?

Tags: python, array, lista, input, split

Boa tarde pessoal, desenvolvendo um código, me deparei com uma dúvida: teria como realizar um `split()` com `n` condições? Ou alguma forma eficiente de fazer?

Por exemplo:

Estou solicitando para um usuário que entre com algumas informações por meio de um `input()`, porém gostaria de realizar o `split()` tanto se ele usar `,` ou `.` quanto se também usar `/` ou `-`.

**Sei que não funciona**, visto que a documentação está apresentando essa hierarquia `str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`, estava pensando em algo funcional que fosse parecido com:

```
information_list = list(input('Enter the informations: ').split(',', '.', '/', '-'))
```

Como retorno, desejo ter uma lista com os valores que o usuário digitou separados pelos 'argumentos' que citei acima. Porém, caso tenham outros método para indicar à fim de realizar algo parecido, também seria de grande valia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o `regex.split()` que usa uma expressão regular para montar o separador. Por exemplo:

```
import re
a = "a,b.c|d"
re.split("[,\.|-]",a)
```

Que retornará a lista:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Giovanni.